# Restangular getList() does not return array of list items

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I try to use Restangular to handle calls to my restful API.

Here is my code:

```
var baseStories = Restangular.all('stories/all');

baseStories.getList().then(function (stories) {
    console.log(stories);
})
```

The console.log shows the full restangularized array instead of an array of stories as I'd expect.

I use the RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor from the docs to unwrap the response data.

Has anyone an idea what I'm missing?

**Edit:**
Below is a screenshot of the console.log output from the code above. I see two stories (which is correct) and a bunch of Restangular methods. Is it possible to only get the stories?

[image: Screenshot of console.log]

Comment: can you add the output of `console.log(stories)` to your question ?

Comment: it will also be useful if you add `console.log(data)` inside `RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function(data,...` to see the structure of the received data.

Comment: I edited my original question and added a (huge) screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually `addResponseInterceptor` must return restangularized element. It is written in the documentation:

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#addresponseinterceptor

In order to get clean response you have to call `plain()` method on the `response` element:

```
var baseStories = Restangular.all('stories/all');

baseStories.getList().then(function (response) {
    $scope.stories = response.plain();
})
```

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was missing. Thanks!